# Cut part of a string in the midle but keep start and end

Tags: php

i have a string like this `300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/file.txt`
I need to cut the **file** and keep the rest, but the string may change even the **txt** can change for another thing like **ini**. I have look into **substr** and **str_split** but i cant figure out how to do it. Any ideias on how to achieve this? I tought about a cycle but cant gifure out how to do it.
EDIT:
I want to replace file with a string. So the desire output will be `00.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/mystring.txt`

Comment: What does "cut the file" mean here?  What is the expected output?

Comment: I suspect what you're trying to do is something like "find the position of the last `/` character, and the first position of `.` after the last `/`, and return that text." Are you looking to pass in `300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/file.txt` to a function and return the string `file`?

Comment: sorry i have updated my question with a example. I want to substitute file with mystring so it would be 00.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/MyString.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a [`pathInfo` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) that will do most of the work for you to parse out the filename/extension. Then you can concat the path back together with the new filename:

```
<?php

function replaceFileName($input, $newFileName) {
    $info = pathInfo($input);
    return $info['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newFileName . '.' . $info['extension'];
}

$test = "300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/file.txt";
var_dump(replaceFileName($test, 'testing'));
// string(53) "300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/testing.txt"
```

Example at https://3v4l.org/TGi4X

`var_dump($info)` will show you how the path was parsed:

```
array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
  string(41) "300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source"
  ["basename"]=>
  string(8) "file.txt"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "txt"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(4) "file"
}
```

This method is preferred compared to using `str_replace` in case your path contains the filename as other parts of the path (an extreme example: `/txt/txt/txt/txt.txt`).

```
<?php

$test = "/txt/txt/txt/txt.txt";
var_dump(replaceFileName($test, 'testing'));
```

Correctly returns: `string(28) "/txt/txt/txt/testing.txt"`

Example at https://3v4l.org/B192t

Comment: thanks bro it works great! I finally got it but i had like 8 lines of code, yours is way cleaner. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, in this way your string will be an array and then you can manipulate as you wish

```
$string = "/data/source/file.txt";
$explode = explode("/", $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 'cut the file' you mean removing everything after the `:` character, then you can use `explode`, as Gabriele mentioned.

In your case it would look like this:

```
$string = '300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/file.txt';
$parts = explode(':', $string);

echo $parts[0]; // 3000.300.300.220
echo $parts[1]; // /var/lib/test/data/source/file.tx
```

Comment: sorry i expressed bad. what i need is to substitute the File with a string i have in another var, so it would be 00.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/MyString.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
$filePath = "300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/file.txt";
$mySting = 'myString';
```

**First method:**

```
$fileName = basename($filePath); # file.txt
$fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); # txt
$newFileName = "{$mySting}.{$fileExtension}"; # myString.txt
$result = str_replace($fileName, $newFileName, $filePath); # 300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/myString.txt
```

**Second method:**

```
$result = explode('/', $filePath); # Array
$fileName = array_pop($result); # file.txt
$fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); # txt
$newFileName = "{$mySting}.{$fileExtension}"; # myString.txt
$result = implode('/', $result); # 300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source  
$newFilePath = "{$result}/{$newFileName}"; # 300.300.300.220:/var/lib/test/data/source/myString.txt
```

**There are other methods**

Comment: You'd still have to add the new file name

Comment: the problem is that i need the last digits and the. file.txt i need the .txt. And with the pop i lose that string

Comment: You want to replace the desired name with the file name. it's true? Post edited

Comment: yes, already got it thanks to your first answer, i did it in 7 lines, but someone has posted one with 2 lines. Thanks for the help bud!